# How to print text output in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and Javascript. I want to ask how to create a textbox (not an input field) that I can print text from a certain input? It's something like console.log, but instead of outputting to the console, I want to output to a textbox like the Directions box below in the picture. The output will be a JSON string fetched from a Spark server

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LJLJ.jpg)

Comment: you just need `textarea`

Comment: @Andres: textarea is like an input text field. I want to create a rectangle with text in it

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a an empty [div](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) in your html, that gets set with javascript as soon as you receive the desired response from your Spark server.

For example:

**html:** `<div id="text-box"></div>`

**javascript:** `document.getElementById("text-box").innerHTML = "[INSERT SPARK RESPONSE HERE]"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in ReactJS, you can try building a function component to render the console-like messages into jsx (your text wrapped in `<p>` tags), and then wrap this component into a `<div>` container. Then you can style the container so it looks like your direction box.

```
//App.js
import "./styles.css";

function TextBoxContent() {
  // JSON obj from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON#arrays_as_json
  const exampleJSON = [
    {
      name: "Molecule Man",
      age: 29,
      secretIdentity: "Dan Jukes",
      powers: ["Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast"]
    },
    {
      name: "Madame Uppercut",
      age: 39,
      secretIdentity: "Jane Wilson",
      powers: [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    }
  ];

  const parseJsonIntoConsoleStr = (item, index) => {
    return (
      <p key={index}>
        {item.name}'s true identity is {item.secretIdentity}
      </p>
    );
  };

  return exampleJSON.map(parseJsonIntoConsoleStr);
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Textbox example</h1>
      <div className="example-text-box">
        <TextBoxContent />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Styling:

```
// style.css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.example-text-box {
  border: black 2px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[Link to demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-textbox-reactjs-33d11)